# How to get Wikidata Labels using Python?

Tags: python, wikidata

For example, I have a Wikidata relation `Q134041`, how can I get the label `website`?

Answer (score 0):

You may use wikidata Python module qwikidata.

```
from qwikidata.sparql  import return_sparql_query_results

query_string = """
        SELECT $WDid
         WHERE {
          ?WDid (wdt:P279)* wd:Q4022
        }"""

res = return_sparql_query_results(query_string)

for row in res["results"]["bindings"]:
   print(row["yourFieldName"]["value"])
```